# How to generate a column with a count of number of points in a polygon AND have 0 for the rows where there are no points in the polygon?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, attribute-joins, point-in-polygon

I have two data sets with a large number of points that I’m organizing into a hexbin grid.

I'm associating these points with the hexbin polygons by using PostGIS to determine if a point falls within a hexbin polygon. The problem with my initial query is that if `st_contains` or `st_intersects` returned false, then I didn’t get the polygon geometry at all. It was simply a hexagon shaped hole in my map. What I wanted to return, instead, was the geometry and then a `count` of 0. So, when there is an intersection, return the polygon + the count (this is a common operation and many previous questions cover how to do this). But I also want to return the rows where `st_disjoints` is `true` and have the count (of points in the polygon) be 0. I can do this with these CTEs and a union:

```
with disjoint_table as (
    select
        a.the_geom_webmercator,
        a.cartodb_id,
        0 as count
    from
        hexbin_polygons_table a
        LEFT join points_table b on st_intersects(a.the_geom_webmercator, b.the_geom_webmercator)
    where
        b.the_geom_webmercator IS NULL
),
intersect_table as (
    select
        a.the_geom_webmercator,
        a.cartodb_id,
        count(b.the_geom_webmercator)
    from
        hexbin_polygons_table a
        join points_table b on st_contains(a.the_geom_webmercator, b.the_geom_webmercator)
    group by
        a.the_geom_webmercator,
        a.cartodb_id
)
select
    *
from
    disjoint_table
union
select
    *
from
    intersect_table
```

The `disjoint_table` part (left join where is NULL...etc.) comes from [Paul Ramsey's answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/210937/160467)

This CTE + `union` works but is very slow. Is there a simpler or better way to get this sort of thing?

Comment: Research the use of an `OUTER JOIN` to match even when no rows match, and the `Coalesce()` function to map NULL to zero.

Comment: @Vince That approach makes sense. But getting `FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions`

Comment: `left outer join` seems to be the winner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Vince mentions in comments, the key here is to include all non-matching rows from the joined relation in the result; this is trivially solved using a `LEFT|RIGHT|FULL [OUTER] JOIN`, where the thus denoted relation(s) will pass all (unfiltered) rows to the [result set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#/media/File%3ASQL_Join_-_01_A_Left_Join_B.svg), with or without fulfilled match condition.
In the result set, `1:n` matches will be represented as expected, having duplicated row selections from the joined relation for multiple matches of a row condition in the join relation, while non-matches of the joined table will have `NULL` values in join relation columns.

However, there's no need for a `COALESCE` here if you `COUNT` rows from the join relation explicitly, as an all-`NULL` set is counted as `0`.

Run

```
SELECT ply.id,
       COUNT(pnt.*) AS cnt
FROM   <polygon> AS ply
LEFT JOIN
       <point> AS pnt
  ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pnt.geom)
GROUP BY
       ply.id
;
```

Comment: If it were `count(geom)`, then `coalesce(count(geom),0)` *would* be necessary.

Comment: This was it. Now I know that `count(table.*)` works differently than `count(table.column_a)`

Comment: @Vince `COUNT` *cannot* return `NULL`?

Comment: Doh, yes. But that was the issue, indirectly.