# Deleting points in in certain area using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, delete

Have a set of points cali_dairies and wanted to delete some of the locations in southern California. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6):

A bit more idiomatic, using a potentially faster `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH
  -- get a GEOMETRY representing the areas to keep
  aoi AS (
    SELECT
      ST_SetSRID(
        ST_Extent(geom),
        4326
      ) AS ext
    FROM
      weather_points
  )
DELETE
FROM
  cali_dairies AS cd
WHERE
  -- for each row execute the actual check; we only need to know if the condition is met once...
  NOT EXISTS (
    -- ...so whenever this query would return at least one row, it breaks out of execution
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      aoi
    -- the actual condition is a bounding box overlap check, fully index driven
    WHERE
      cd.geom && aoi.ext
  )
;
```

---

**Update:**

The query above is suitable for the general case of comparing against a set/table of AOIs.
If, and *only if*, the compared set contains a *single row only,* the issue with disjoint queries do not exist, and the query can be further simplified:

```
WITH
  -- get a GEOMETRY representing the areas to keep
  aoi AS (
    SELECT
      ST_SetSRID(
        ST_Extent(geom),
        4326
      ) AS ext
    FROM
      weather_points
  )
DELETE
FROM
  cali_dairies AS cd
USING
  aoi
WHERE
  NOT cd.geom && aoi.ext
;
```

---

Make sure you have an index on `cali_dairies.geom`.

Comment: Should that be `EXISTS` instead of `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Why is this faster than using `WHERE ST_Intersects(cd.geom, aoi.geom)`?

Comment: @dr_jts looks like OP wants to.delete from an anti-join on that extent. `&&` should comply wirh the actual index condition and does not invoke a function call.

Comment: `EXISTS` cannot really play out its advantages here as there cannot be an early exit. However, this reads "*Traverse the table, check for index driven box overlap and delete if not found.*" while the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in OPs answer reads something like "*Create a left open set intersection on index supported geometric containment check and with a filter for NULL column values, gather column values into a hash map, traverse the table, check column values against the hash and delete if found.*.

Comment: ah right, did not see that OP was deleting where not in an area, rather than in it.

Comment: This is such a cool query. I wished I understood it better. I bet if someone would break down each part, a lot of people would appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see a good answer, I did use this question/answer (especially the second answer by Paul Ramsey) which was very helpful: [Querying points inside and outside of polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210387/querying-points-inside-and-outside-of-polygons)

Here is my solution

```
-- create rectangle polygon to act as boundary (4 coordinates of yet another points table)
create view v_dairies_in_target as
    select 1 as id, geom from 
    (select st_makepolygon(st_geomfromtext(
        'linestring('||min(lon)||' '||max(lat)||','
        ||min(lon)||' '||min(lat)||','||max(lon)||' '||min(lat)||','
        ||max(lon)||' '||max(lat)||','
        ||min(lon)||' '||max(lat)||')'))::geometry(Polygon,4326) as geom from weather_points) as sq;

-- delete points not in the rectangle
delete from cali_dairies where ogc_fid = any (
    select pts.ogc_fid as pts from cali_dairies pts 
    left join v_dairies_in_target poly on (st_within(pts.geom, poly.geom))
    where poly.id is null);

drop view v_dairies_in_target;

select * from cali_dairies -- check it!
commit;
```